# Finding Range of a function - Discrete

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let f, g and h be the following functions.

$f:Z \rightarrow \{-1,1\} \text{ defined as }
f(x) =\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $ x $ is even} \\
-1, & \text{if $ x $ is odd}
\end{cases} 
$

$ g:Z \rightarrow R \text{ defined as }
 g(x) = x^2 - \frac 12
$

$
h:\{x|x\in R  \land x \ge 0 \} \rightarrow R \text{ defined as }
 h(x) =\sqrt{\mathstrut x} + 2 $

Determine the range of $ f,g $ and $ h $

My answers are $\{1,1\}$ for $f$

Comment: I'm not sure how to find range of $g$ and $h$

Comment: In the definition of $g$, did you wrote $f(x)=...$ by mistake?

Comment: The range of $f$ is $\{\color{red}{-1}, 1\}$ since $f$ assumes the value $1$ when $x$ is even and $-1$ when $x$ is odd.  Have you tried graphing $g(x) = x^2 - \frac{1}{2}$ and $h(x) = \sqrt{x} + 2$ to see what $y$-values they assume?

Comment: This was a question from Discrete Tutorial, I doubt there's involvement of graphing since that is calculus

Answer (score 0):

The range of $f$ is $$\{-1,1\}$$

The range of $g$ is $$\{-1/2, 1/2, 7/2, 17/2, 31/2, ..., (2n^2-1)/2,...\}$$

The range of $h$ is the interval $$[2, \infty)$$